# Equivalence relation defined on multi-indices (equality patterns).

Tags: equivalence-relations

I'm trying to understand the following things.

Let $\{1, \dots , n\}:=[n]$ and consider multi-indices $\textbf{a,b} \in [n]^l$ for some integer $l$.

Let's define an equivalence relation $\textbf{a}\sim \textbf{b} \Leftrightarrow \textbf{a}_i = \textbf{a}_j \Leftrightarrow \textbf{b}_i = \textbf{b}_j \, \, \forall i,j \in [l].$  (equality patterns)

Which are the equivalence classes of a such relation? Can you provide me some simple examples even with $l=2$?

Let's say that $n=2, l=2$.

so if $\textbf{a} = (1,1) \Rightarrow \textbf{b} = (1,1)$ or $\textbf{b} = (2,2)$

if $\textbf{a} = (2,2) \Rightarrow \textbf{b} = (1,1)$ or $\textbf{b} = (2,2)$

if $\textbf{a} = (1,2) \Rightarrow \textbf{b} = (1,2)$ or $\textbf{b} = (2,1)$

if $\textbf{a} = (2,1) \Rightarrow \textbf{b} = (1,2)$ or $\textbf{b} = (2,1)$

This is what I manage to get but I still have several perplexities about which the equivalence classes are in this case.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  If, say, $n$ is small then you should be able to list all the tuples by hand and simply check.

Comment: Ok I've just expanded out a simple case but I still have some perplexities :(

Comment: So for $l=2$, you should be able to see all the cases.  In general, you'll need to look at partitions of $l$, one block (of restricted size) in which no terms match, and then constant blocks.  I'm not sure the characterization will be pleasant for large $n$.

Comment: but which are the equivalence classes? Why are they the partitions of $l$ in this case?

Comment: Maybe since I only have two possible cases $(1,1) \sim (2,2)$ and the other where they are different then ok I have two different eqivalence classes. But is there a way to write them explicitly?

Comment: On the paper I'm reading they write them to be $\gamma_1 =\{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$ and $\gamma_2 = \{\{1,2\}\}$ to refer when $i \neq j$ and $i =j$ respectively but I don't understand why.

Comment: With $l=2$ the equivalence classes are just $(a,b)$ with $a\neq b$ and $(a,a)$.  For higher $l$ I think it gets messy.

Comment: I take it back, it is not hard.  For each $l-$tuple, partition it according to the digits (so all the $1's$ are in one block, and so on).  The equivalence classes are just determined by these partitions (that is, two $l-$tuples are equivalent iff the partitions they give rise to are equivalent.).

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Given an $l-$tuple, $(a_1, \cdots, a_l)$ we define a partition of $\{1, \cdots l\}$ according to the digits in the tuple.

Thus, with $l=7, n=5$, the $6-$tuple $(3,3,5,1,3,5,3)$ we would get the partition $\{(1,2,5,7),\,(3,6), (4)\}$.

Then:  two $l-$tuples are equivalent iff they define the same partition.

Indeed, the partition tells you precisely which "blocks" of indices must have a common digit.

Note:  as an example, take $l=2$.  There are only two partitions of $\{1,2\}$, namely $\{(1,2)\}$ and $\{(1),(2)\}$.  The first gives you the pairs of the form $(a,a)$ and the second gives you the pairs of the form $(a,b)$ with $a\neq b$.